# Access and password management on Mac OS

Tags: mac, passwords, operating-systems, password-management, password-generation

is it possible to perform user authentication management with passwords in access control on a Mac computer with a recent Mac OS operating system?
Require users passwords with a minimum length of 12 characters, change passwords every X time, not being able to use old passwords?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "temporary passwords"? Are these federated accounts (SAMBA, AD)? Are you trying to control access in a business or shared environment, or is this your home computer?

Comment: mcaOS standard Keychain password fill will generate [& remember] random passwords that fit your criteria, but there's nothing to force a new password after an interval [this is also not recommended by any government authority any more, as users use regular patterns &/or write them down] Keychain will also warn if using a common or repeated password. Example of a Keychain-generated pass - `8tW-Y32-g52-RF4`

Comment: music2myear, thank you for yout reply

Please explain what you mean by "temporary passwords"?
I mean this policy needs to change password after a X period of time.

Are these federated accounts? I don't know, I think it is Active Directory. I'm just a newbie but it is a policy required by a client on my home working computer..

it is a computer for work from my home. without shared with anybody else, but client required me a management and policy about users and passwords. And I don't know how to create this on Mac OS Catalina environment.